# ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.springframework.web

Tags: java, spring, myeclipse

I have no idea what's happening. I have a java project, that was developed in MyEclipse without `Maven or Gradle`.

```
INFORMACIÓN: Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
ene 23, 2018 1:19:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myproject]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more
ene 23, 2018 1:19:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
GRAVE: Error durante el despliegue del directorio C:\Users\pepe\Workspaces\MyEclipse 2017\.metadata\.me_tcat85\webapps\myproject de la aplicación web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myproject]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ene 23, 2018 1:19:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

I was reading that maybe the problem was the **spring version** but I couldn't upgrade it.

[image]

The actual spring version is 2.5

Details: We need to migrate the project to a newer server, that server is running `Apache tomcat 8.0.47` with `JVM 1.8.0_151` when we tried to deploy the .war the error above appeared, after searching we found that it is because the compiler version is not equal to the jre version of the server, I changed the version to JRE 1.8 but again the same error was generated, then in another forum it said that in MyEclipse I had to change the server runtime, so I put `MyEclipse Tomcat 8.5 Runtime Libraries`, once more time the same error appeared, finally I saw in another forum that the phrase "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:142)" is because the spring version is not compatible any more, and I tried to change it but I couldn't.

Comment: Wow, Spring 2.5 is _ancient_.  What else changed? Maybe you upgraded some other library and it is no longer compatible with such an old Spring version?

Comment: Just I changed jre 1.6 to 1.8 and added MyEclipse Tomcat 8.5 Runtime Libraries

Comment: I use Spring 2.5.6 where I work. We can't use Java 8 because of it. Try using Java 7 and see if that works.

Comment: I changed but it didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what was the problem but for me it was easier create an empty maven project and the put there my files without libraries, add dependencies in the pom file, keeping the `java version 1.6`.